# How to Make class="form-row" fixed and how to put label and textbox in a straight line?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a simple bootstrap form with the following fields, now the problem is

1. The Labels and text box are not in straight line.
2. When i change the **Notes** field size it is effecting remaining fields, they are moving down(see the screenshot point 2), how to make those fields fixed and how make label and text in a straight line

[image: Screenshot]

**below is the runnable code, please help me by editing below
(open the snippet full page).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
.mydiv
{
   
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>




<div class="mydiv">

<div class="container">

              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">FirstName</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="FirstName">
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label class="col-sm-2">StartDate</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7" >
                         <div class="form-group">
                         <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">LastName</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="LastName">
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label class="col-sm-2">EndDate</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7" >
                         <div class="form-group">
                         <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
                                  
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test1:</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="test1">
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test2:</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="test2">
                     </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                          
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test3</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="test3">
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test4 Id</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                     </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test5</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">Notes</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                     </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style='clear:both'></div>              
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test6</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="test6">
                     </div>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <div style='clear:both'></div>
              
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test7</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="test7">
                     </div>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <div style='clear:both'></div>
              
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test8</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="test8">
                     </div>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <div style='clear:both'></div>
              
              

              
</div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

code.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if this code works for you by adding it to your CSS:

```
.form-group{
          display:flex;
          align-items:center;
        } 
 
 
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  
#w3review {
  position: absolute;
}        
}
```

working example:

```css
.form-group{
          display:flex;
          align-items:center;
        } 
 
 
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  
#w3review {
  position: absolute;
}        
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
.mydiv
{
   
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>




<div class="mydiv">

<div class="container">

              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">FirstName</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="FirstName">
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label class="col-sm-2">StartDate</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7" >
                         <div class="form-group">
                         <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">LastName</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="LastName">
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label class="col-sm-2">EndDate</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7" >
                         <div class="form-group">
                         <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
                                  
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test1:</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="test1">
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test2:</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="test2">
                     </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                          
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test3</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="test3">
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test4 Id</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                     </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test5</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                     </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">Notes</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                     </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style='clear:both'></div>              
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test6</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="test6">
                     </div>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <div style='clear:both'></div>
              
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test7</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="test7">
                     </div>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <div style='clear:both'></div>
              
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label  class="col-sm-2">test8</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="test8">
                     </div>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <div style='clear:both'></div>
              
              

              
</div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your Style to make label and textbox in a straight line

```
 .form-group{
          display:flex;
          align-items:center;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for response Label and textbox are now in straight line, but how solve point 2.  still when i change the textarea size it is effecting remaining fields.

Comment: text-area issue fixed, after adding                                                                      
     #w3review {
  position: absolute;
}